# download a file from server using a controller and javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, fileresult

I have the controller code below:

```
public FileResult DownloadFileParaView()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"MyPath");
    string fileName = "MyFileName";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

How can I call it from JavaScript to return my file? Does I have to copy the file to project content?

Comment: Are you trying to trigger a download prompt, or just return a file for your JavaScript code to interpret in some fashion?

Comment: I just want to open the typical download window where client can save the file to his PC

Comment: the fileName also need to have the extension

Comment: This is an HTTP endpoint, so call it like you would any other HTTP endpoint.

Comment: could any of you provide some code example please?

Comment: There are *countless* examples of that already.  People have used JavaScript to call HTTP endpoints for over 20 years.  Google "javascript ajax" or "javascript get http" or "javascript fetch".  You get the idea.

Comment: Also google "site:stackoverflow.com javascript fileresult", and notice you'll get some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're calling this from within a view, it's relatively simple:

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("DownloadFileParaView")';
```

This would be in a script tag within the view where you want to trigger the download.